# How to make load testing, query analysis in asp.net web application for a academic project

Tags: c#, asp.net, load-testing, stress-testing

I have developed a e-commerce web application in asp.net using sql server (stored procedures and using linqtosql). I want to perform load testing, stress testing, response time for client when he requests server pages, and i also want to analyse the time the application takes to execute the sql instructions/retrieving the data from database.

How can i perform this analysis ? I'm a student in a university, so the tools that i have at my disposal are quite limited.

Help me out !!

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A free tool for load testing is [Microsoft's WCat](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1466&g=6).

From the product description:

> Web Capacity Analysis Tool (WCAT) is a
>   lightweight HTTP load generation tool
>   primarily designed to measure the
>   performance of a web server within a
>   controlled environment.  WCAT can
>   simulate thousands of concurrent users
>   making requests to a single web site
>   or multiple web sites.  The WCAT
>   engine uses a simple script to define
>   the set of HTTP requests to be played
>   back to the web server. Extensibility
>   is provided through plug-in DLLs and a
>   standard, simple API.

Answer (score 1):

Another free load testing tool is [StresStimulus](http://stresstimulus.stimulustechnology.com/) fiddler add-on, offered by our firm. It does not require scripting or using API, since it simply replays sessions recorded in fiddler. Free edition allows up to 1500 users. The average response time of every request is presented in a grid while instant performance characteristics are displayed in graphs.

To analyze the sql instructions time you can use SQL profiles since you already have SQL server.